# Table isn't displaying

Tags: tables, excel2latex, aastex

```
\documentclass[manuscript]{aastex}
\begin{document}

\clearpage

\begin{deluxetable}{}
\tabletypesize{\scriptsize}
\rotate
\tablecaption{Sample table taken from \citet{treu03}\label{tbl-1}}
\tablewidth{0pt}
\tablehead{
\colhead{Mon ID} & \colhead{U} & \colhead{B} & \colhead{V} & \colhead{R} &
\colhead{I} & \colhead{u} & \colhead{g} &
\colhead{i} & \colhead{J} &
\colhead{Jerr} & \colhead{H} & \colhead{Herr} & \colhead{K} & \colhead{Kerr} & \colhead{IRAC1} & \colhead{I1err} & \colhead{IRAC2} & \colhead{I2err} & \colhead{IRAC3} & \colhead{I3err} & \colhead{IRAC4} & \colhead{I4err} & \colhead{MIPS24} & \colhead{M24err} & \colhead{SpT} & \colhead{HaEW} & \colhead{RA} & \colhead{DEC} & \colhead{Mean I1} & \colhead{Mean I2} & \colhead{alpha K24} & \colhead{Class} & \colhead{alpha K8} & \colhead{Av}}

\startdata
Mon-000101 & 99.999 & 99.999 & 99.999 & 99.999 & 99.999 & 99.999 & 99.999 & 99.999 & 99.999 & 16.749 & 99.999 & 16.253 & 99.999 & 99.999 & 99.999 & 11.142 & 0.014 & 10.05 & 0.007 & 9.091 & 0.028 & 8.326 & 0.066 & 99.999 & 99.999 & null  & -99.999 & 100.27242 & 9.608597 & 11.082 & 10.034 & 0.39  & I     & 0.39  & 31.1 \\
    Mon-000171 & 99.999 & 99.999 & 24.485 & 22.18 & 19.966 & 99.999 & 99.999 & 99.999 & 99.999 & 99.999 & 99.999 & 99.999 & 99.999 & 99.999 & 99.999 & 14.942 & 0.058 & 14.479 & 0.111 & 13.639 & 1.256 & 12.11 & 0.302 & 99.999 & 99.999 & null  & -99.999 & 100.2923 & 9.52286 & 14.834 & 14.385 & 0.45  & I     & 0.45  & 33.7 \\
\enddata
\end{document}
```

(Above) is a small piece of the table I'm trying to produce. Basically I've just copy/pasted my data (translated using `excel2latex`), into a sample.tex document that came in the `aastex` package. When I try to view the PDF (sorry, not too familiar with the LaTeX lingo) I get this as an error:

```
./sample.tex:600: Use of /@array doesn't match its definition.
<argument> \edef \reserved@a {
    \reserved@a x}\advance \@tempcnta \m@ne
1.600 \startdata

?
```

I have no idea what that means, or where my problem lies. Thanks in advance for any pointers, assistance, general help.

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Sorry about that, it slipped my mind. I hope my edit is sufficient. The sample document is huge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd not seen this environment before but `texdoc aastex` reveals that the argument should be an r l or c for each column. Also you were missing the `\end{deluxetable}`

```
\begin{deluxetable}{rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr}
\tabletypesize{\scriptsize}
\rotate
\tablecaption{Sample table taken from \citet{treu03}\label{tbl-1}}
\tablewidth{0pt}
\tablehead{
\colhead{Mon ID} & \colhead{U} & \colhead{B} & \colhead{V} & \colhead{R} &
\colhead{I} & \colhead{u} & \colhead{g} &
\colhead{i} & \colhead{J} &
\colhead{Jerr} & \colhead{H} & \colhead{Herr} & \colhead{K} & \colhead{Kerr} & \colhead{IRAC1} & \colhead{I1err} & \colhead{IRAC2} & \colhead{I2err} & \colhead{IRAC3} & \colhead{I3err} & \colhead{IRAC4} & \colhead{I4err} & \colhead{MIPS24} & \colhead{M24err} & \colhead{SpT} & \colhead{HaEW} & \colhead{RA} & \colhead{DEC} & \colhead{Mean I1} & \colhead{Mean I2} & \colhead{alpha K24} & \colhead{Class} & \colhead{alpha K8} & \colhead{Av}}
\startdata
Mon-000101 & 99.999 & 99.999 & 99.999 & 99.999 & 99.999 & 99.999 & 99.999 & 99.999 & 99.999 & 16.749 & 99.999 & 16.253 & 99.999 & 99.999 & 99.999 & 11.142 & 0.014 & 10.05 & 0.007 & 9.091 & 0.028 & 8.326 & 0.066 & 99.999 & 99.999 & null  & -99.999 & 100.27242 & 9.608597 & 11.082 & 10.034 & 0.39  & I     & 0.39  & 31.1 \\
    Mon-000171 & 99.999 & 99.999 & 24.485 & 22.18 & 19.966 & 99.999 & 99.999 & 99.999 & 99.999 & 99.999 & 99.999 & 99.999 & 99.999 & 99.999 & 99.999 & 14.942 & 0.058 & 14.479 & 0.111 & 13.639 & 1.256 & 12.11 & 0.302 & 99.999 & 99.999 & null  & -99.999 & 100.2923 & 9.52286 & 14.834 & 14.385 & 0.45  & I     & 0.45  & 33.7 \\
\enddata
\end{deluxetable}
```

Comment: Awesome. That got the compilation going. Now there's a new problem...it cuts off after the 19th column. Hmmm. I understand that it might a better idea to post a new question, but if you can I'd like to understand why it's doing that. Thank you.

Comment: @Matt well it's just too big, you need to use a smaller font or use cells that line wrap or something

Comment: That makes sense. I was hoping there was a quick line I could add to fix it. Oh well, I'll start messing around with it. Thanks again for you help.